# Different polling delay for different suppliers in Spring Cloud Stream Function

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function

I'm trying to implement suppliers using Spring Cloud Function and Kafka. I need that one supplier should publish after every 10 secs and other should publish after every 30 secs. I could see from documentation, I can change delay using `spring.cloud.stream.poller.fixed-delay` property. [Reference](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_suppliers_sources)

But I need to set different delay for each topic. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From the spring-cloud-function perspective there isn't any kind of polling as it is not the responsibility of the framework.
From the spring-cloud-stream perspective that uses spring-cloud-function indeed there is a mechanism that you have described. However, keep in mind that spring-cloud-stream is primarily designed to support concept of microservices (not your general messaging framework) and in microservices we embrace *do one thing but do it well without affecting others* approach. So having more then one supplier kind of goes against this model.
If you are building a general purpose messaging app, then i'd suggest to use [Spring Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html) framework which provides all the necessary hooks to accomplish what you need, but will require a bit more configuration details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to courtesy of Oleg this feature is now implemented, here is [PR](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/commit/3e9fc5152e446438bd52c7c9d028bccbacb42c8d#diff-e0a39067f5e864aa39b96d295c19a7852fce275ab8823bf51b59242e115ce677). Now we can define poller per producer like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.supply-out-0.producer.poller.fixed-delay=3000
```

See also: [Configure Poller for the specific supplier in Spring Cloud Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67871341/configure-poller-for-the-specific-supplier-in-spring-cloud-stream?rq=3)