# Configure Poller for the specific supplier in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, poller

I have an application with multiple suppliers. So, I'm trying to configure `fixed-delay` for the specific supplier in Spring Cloud Stream. Example:

**application.yaml**

```
    spring:
      cloud:
        function:
          definition: produce;produce2 
        stream:
          poller:
            produce: 
              fixedDelay: 10000L
            produce2:
              fixedDelay: 5000L 
          bindings:
            produce-out-0:
              destination: string-output
            produce2-out-0:
              destination: string-output-2
```

**code snippet**

```
    @Configuration
    public class ProducerConfiguration {
    
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerConfiguration.class);
        
        @Bean
        public Supplier<Object> produce() {
            return () -> {
                LOGGER.info("message");
                return "message";
            };
        }
        
        @Bean
        public Supplier<Object> produce2() {
            return () -> {
                LOGGER.info("message-2");
                return "message-2";
            };
        }
    
    }
```

But according to spring's documentation *https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_polling_configuration_properties*, It seems to only be able to configure a `org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.DefaultPollerProperties` bean for whole suppliers in an application. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed this is not supported for functional programming model at the moment as it really violates a concept of microservices for which spring-cloud-stream was designed for, where one of the main principles is *you do one thing and do it well without affecting others*. And in your case (especially with sources) you have multiple microservices grouped together in a single JVM process, thus one service affecting another.

That said, feel free to [raise an issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues) so we can consider adding this feature

Comment: I also have same requirement where I need to set separate cron job for different supplier. Do we have issue for this or should I raise one?

Comment: Raised - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2280